# Data from WebService is not retained in page history

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, history, toolkitscriptmanager

Here is my scenario:

I am using a web service to pass back search results. To do this I am using ToolkitScriptManager with a ServiceReference to my web service and calling the web service up with javascript. The javascript call looks something like this:

```
WebService.GetResults("search term", OnSuccessGetData, OnFail);
```

If the request is successful the "OnSuccessGetData" function is fired and the results are inserted into a DIV tag. Because the resulting search results can be large I wrote the service to only pass back the first 20 results on the first trip. After that I make calls again to the service to return the next 5 results and continue to do this until all the results are loaded. This all works wonderful.

You can see it in action at www.lsbio.com and use the search term "human mouse". My problem is that when the user clicks on a product and then hits the 'Back' button, the search results have to be fetched again from the webservice.

Is there a way to keep the search results in the DIV tag to remain as part of the page so when the user navigates away from the search page and uses the 'Back' button to navigate back, the search results are still there without having to hit the webservice again?

If I did not make myself clear enough on what I am trying to do, please test the site www.lsbio.com, use the search terms human mouse, click on a product, and then hit the back button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store the result somewhere, i.e. in a hidden field? Than on page load you first test if the result is in the hidden field, if so you insert it in the result area, if not you use the webservice.